# Excel Power query removing rows took forever and intense memory usage

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Good day Friends,

I have a Excel file, that I used Power query editor to pull multiple excel files (same format/columns) into one.

I would like to create a new column to calculate the time different ( duration ) between a "FAULT" row and the "MSG" row that is below the "FAULT" row.

to reduce data size,

removing all the "MSG" rows that are not under "FAULT" rows.

only keeping the "Fault" rows and the "MSG" that is directly underneath it.

[attached picture here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W2GSoQMhedMnQ-PyJgXxqDg2PWUsW1lR/view?usp=sharing)

so i did the following

Step 1 : I added a Index column

Step 2 : use M language to add another column to label the unwanted row.

```
try if [alarm class] = #"Added Index" {[Index] - 1} [alarm class]
then "delete"
else "keep"
otherwise null
```

my query:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("Y:\powerBI\Feng\RMG\ASC07L_20211123_1336.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type datetime}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", Int64.Type}, {"Column7", type text}}),
    #"Inserted Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each Date.From([Column2]), type date),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Date",{{"Column3", "alarm ID"}, {"Column4", "alarm class"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each if [alarm ID] = "CRN_ATOEXEINS" then 1 else if [alarm class] = "FAULT" then 1 else 0),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = 1)),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom.1", each try if [alarm class] = #"Added Index" {[Index] - 1} [alarm class]
then "delete"
else "keep"
otherwise null),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Custom.1] = "keep"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

However when i hit close and Load, the file size increases 100x, and the load time is unbearable.
when it did finishes the render, the file size did shrink to its actual size, which is small then original because the removed columns.

**my question is, am I doing something wrong? is there a better way to do this to increase the querying speed?**

here i attach the link of the excel files, as well as the one that query them together(Book1.xlsx)
for the purpose of fast turnaround, i only query 1 csv file into the book1.xlsx
but i actually needed to query all csv file into book1.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

try this method of pulling the previous row for one column which is much faster then using the index

From Imke Feldmann on the BIaccountant website at one pouint

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Removed Top Rows","alarm class"),1),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Top Rows") & {shiftedList},
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Top Rows") & {"previous row alarm class"})
in custom2
```

Above offsets one single column. You could also offset all columns from original table but likely thats more process intensive. Then add your comparison check

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
MinusOne =  #table({"Column1"}, {{null}}) & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveLastN(Source,1)),1),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ),
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source)&Table.ColumnNames(MinusOne ) )
in custom2
```

specific to your use case, try

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("Y:\powerBI\Feng\RMG\ASC07L_20211123_1336.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type datetime}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", Int64.Type}, {"Column7", type text}}),
#"Inserted Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each Date.From([Column2]), type date),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Date",{{"Column3", "alarm ID"}, {"Column4", "alarm class"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each if [alarm ID] = "CRN_ATOEXEINS" then 1 else if [alarm class] = "FAULT" then 1 else 0),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = 1)),
// new part here:
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Filtered Rows",1),
shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Removed Top Rows","alarm class"),1),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Top Rows") & {shiftedList},
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Top Rows") & {"previous row alarm class"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "check", each if [alarm class] = [previous row alarm class] then "delete" else "keep"),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom2" , each ([check] = "keep"))
in  #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: Hello @horseyride, I tried the first query from you. i'm getting an error message as follow
Expression.Error: The column 'alarm class' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    alarm class

I have added my original query in my post, thanks in advance.

Comment: edited answer above